# What format is the file /var/mail/username mail utilities

Tags: email

I need a sample file where `mail` utility stored messages.

What I mean is:

```
Return-path: <user@example.domain>
Received: from anton by nflogs.domain with local (Exim 4.80)
        (envelope-from <user@example.domain>)
        id 1VuiP9-0006js-Fa; Sun, 22 Dec 2013 19:45:11 +0700
To: man@nflogs.domain
Subject: test
Cc: textCC@example.domain
Message-Id: <E1VuiP9-0006js-Fa@example.domain>
From: Anton <user@example.domain>
Date: Sun, 22 Dec 2013 19:45:11 +0700
```

But I'm not sure that it's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files located at `/var/mail/username` are in a format called mbox. You can read more about this format on the Wikipedia page titled: [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox).

*excerpt of format*

```
From MAILER-DAEMON Fri Jul  8 12:08:34 2011
From: Author <author@example.com>
To: Recipient <recipient@example.com>
Subject: Sample message 1

This is the body.
>From (should be escaped).
There are 3 lines.

From MAILER-DAEMON Fri Jul  8 12:08:34 2011
From: Author <author@example.com>
To: Recipient <recipient@example.com>
Subject: Sample message 2

This is the second body.
```

Comment: mbox starts each new message with '^From', but the format the OP showed (and my own /var/mail/username) starts with 'Return-Path:', what is the difference?